# access to System.Drawing.Rectangle not available in C# class libraries

Tags: c#

I'm designing a C# class library for basic physics in PC games. I'm trying to make an AABB collisions handling function using the built-in rectangle struct, but I can't seem to access it;

```
using System.Drawing;
```

does not work, and it tells me it's unnecessary. However,

```
public static bool AABB(System.Drawing.Rectangle rec1, System.Drawing.Rectangle rec2)
{
   //just for testing at the moment
   return true;
}
```

gives me the following error: `CS0234  C# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

My target is set to `.NET Framework 4.5.2`

Is there a way to access the Rect struct from a class library, or am I better off just setting up my own struct?

Comment: You probably need to add `System.Drawing` to your project references.

Comment: Have you added the `System.Drawing.dll` to your project references? Only adding a using statement is not enough, you have to tell the compiler where to look for the namespaces.

Comment: Unless you have a tool such as ReSharper to suggest, please search MSDN on the class and check carefully on that page which assembly (.DLL) this class is defined in. Then next time you don't have to ask such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added reference to System.Drawing yet?

[image: Error ?]